# Switch to GreenDao from ActiveAndroid

Tags: java, android, android-studio, greendao, activeandroid

i am working on an Android Project in which ActiveAndroid ORM is used but now i want to use GreenDao ORM for the same Project. Can somebody help me with the Steps to be taken for this migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see in both ORM we make model classes ....and access database by creating objects ,...rest you can find best way to implement GreenDao on this [link](https://mindorks.com/blog/powerful-android-orm-greendao-3-tutorial)